# Error : Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

Hello :) I'm trying to display an error message when the user has not put the correct password or username but I have an error in the console (in the title of my question). I saw that many other similar topics were created but none helped me. Apparently, you have to return a component but in my case, Alert is already a component, isn't it?
I specify that my constant error message fills correctly when the person made a typing error (managed with a reducer and a middleware). It is a character string. It's just that I can't display it.. my code is quite long it only concerns this part in the Modal component: Thank you very much!

```
<Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Me connecter</Modal.Title>
          {() => {
            if (!errorMessage !== '') {
              <Alert variant="danger">
                {errorMessage}
              </Alert>;
            }
          } }
        </Modal.Header>
```

WHOLE CODE

```
// import Bootsrap-react's components
import {
  Container,
  Navbar,
  Nav,
  Modal,
  Button,
  Form,
  Alert,
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import logo from 'src/assets/images/logo.png';
import { fetchAllEvents } from '../../actions/events';
import { setSelectedRegionId } from '../../actions/regions';
import { setSelectedGenreId } from '../../actions/genres';
import {
  changeEmail,
  changePassword,
  logIn,
  logOut,
} from '../../actions/user';
import './appHeader.scss';

const AppHeader = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.user.token);
  const emailValue = useSelector((state) => state.user.email);
  const passwordValue = useSelector((state) => state.user.password);
  const errorMessage = useSelector((state) => state.user.errorMessage);
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar id="mainNav" expand="lg">
        <Container id="navbar-container">
          <LinkContainer to="/">
            <Navbar.Brand> <img src={logo} alt="logo" height="60" />
            </Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>
          <LinkContainer to="/">
            <Nav.Link>
              <h2 className="navbar-title">Concert'o</h2>
            </Nav.Link>
          </LinkContainer>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav " placement="right">
            <Nav className="flex-grow-1 justify-content-evenly">
              <LinkContainer
                to="/"
                onClick={() => {
                  dispatch(setSelectedGenreId());
                  dispatch(setSelectedRegionId());
                }}
              >
                <Nav.Link className="navlink-header">Accueil</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/genres">
                <Nav.Link className="navlink-header">Genres</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/regions">
                <Nav.Link className="navlink-header">Regions</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer
                to="/tous-les-evenements"
                onClick={() => {
                  dispatch(setSelectedGenreId());
                  dispatch(setSelectedRegionId());
                  dispatch(fetchAllEvents());
                }}
              >
                <Nav.Link className="navlink-header">Tous les événements</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <Nav.Link
                className="navlink-header "
                onClick={() => {
                  if (token !== null) {
                    dispatch(logOut());
                  }
                  else {
                    setShow(true);
                  }
                }}
              >{!token ? 'Se connecter' : 'Se Déconnecter'}
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={() => setShow(false)}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Me connecter</Modal.Title>
          {() => {
            if (!errorMessage !== '') {
              <Alert variant="danger">
                {errorMessage}
              </Alert>;
            }
          } }
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="email"
                placeholder="name@example.com"
                autoFocus
                email={emailValue}
                onChange={(event) => {
                  // console.log(event.target.value);
                  dispatch(changeEmail(event.target.value));
                }}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group
              className="mb-3"
              controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1"
            >
              <Form.Label>Mot de passe</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="password"
                password={passwordValue}
                onChange={(event) => {
                  // console.log(event.target.value);
                  dispatch(changePassword(event.target.value));
                }}

              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button
            variant="secondary"
            onClick={() => {
              dispatch(logIn());
              // setShow(false);
            }}
          >
            Valider
          </Button>
          <LinkContainer
            to="/inscription"
          >
            <Button onClick={() => setShow(false)} variant="primary">
              Pas encore inscrit ? Cliquez ici
            </Button>
          </LinkContainer>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div>

  );
};
export default AppHeader;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a function and not a component (arrow function):

```
{() => {
if (!errorMessage !== '') {
  <Alert variant="danger">
    {errorMessage}
  </Alert>;
}
} }
```

change it to something like this:

```
{ errorMessage !== '' && <Alert variant="danger">{errorMessage}</Alert> }
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly! But I don't understant why this new line is a component ...?

Comment: "&&" is a logical AND in javascript.  This is a common pattern in React: You can provide a boolean expression. If it's true, then the second expression (our component) is returned. If the boolean expression is false, it's short circuited and the second expression is doesn't evaluated at all and the false is returned. If a javascript expression returnes false, it is not rendered in JSX.

Comment: Your if expression would be valid too, but you wrapped it in an arrow function.  `{ if (!errorMessage !== '') {
  <Alert variant="danger">
    {errorMessage}
  </Alert>;

} }` should work too.

Comment: I understand! thank you very much :)